# Не понимаю как исправть ошибку. В аргументах функции описываю массив и вывожу массив, но выдается ошибка, что int[] не может переобразоваться в int

Tags: java

```
public static int NewMass(int [] arr) {
        task4.getArray(n);
        int[] arr1= new int[arr.length];
        int max = arr[0];
        for (int j : arr ){
            if(max<arr[j])
                max = arr[j];
        }for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if(arr[i]<0)
                    arr1[i] = arr[i]+max;
                else if (arr[i]==0)
                    arr1[i]=1;
                else
                    arr1[i]=arr[i]*2;
            }for (int c :arr1) {
            System.out.println(arr1[c]);
        }return arr1;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не стоит вписывать в название вопроса весь текст. Оставьте там только основное

Answer (score 1):

Вы указали что метод возвращает int - просто одно целое число:

```
public static int NewMass
```

а пытаетесь вернуть вместо этого `int[]` - массив целых чисел:

```
return arr1;
```

Замените в заголовке метода `int` на `int[]` и всё должно скомпилиться.